# objects dont pass through cylinder

Tags: objects, rigidbody

so basically i created a cylinder, i deleted its one face, and i made some cubes to get into the cylinder but when i try to do that cubes just dont get in the cylinder, instead they crash to the invincible face of the cylinder which is the face that i deleted. i really need help. (also both the cube and the cylinder has rigidbody's and there is no problem with the rigidbody) [image: the cylinder and the cube]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For you cylinder object, choose *Collisions > Shape > Mesh*:

[image]